# SATA Drive is not detected when hotswapping

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, ahci

So from what I've read online, if AHCI is enabled in the BIOS, I should be able to hot-swap a SATA drive and it will supposedly *"just work"*.

However, that has not been my experience.

When I hot-swap a SATA drive on my system, it is never detected. It doesn't show up in `lsblk`, it doesn't show up in Gparted, nothing even shows in `dmesg`.

So, I am wondering what the issue is?

I am using 16.04 on an Asus M5A97 R2.0

---

Edit to address Takkat's suggestion:

I have no such option:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

SATA hot plugging needs to be allowed with a setting in some BIOSes. The names of this may differ, ranging from *allow hot-plug* to *eSATA*.

For the ASUS M5A97 the relevant BIOS setting is in *Advanced > SATA Configuration > SB SATA Configuration*:

> *SATA Hot Plug on Port1~6 [Disabled]*
>   These items appear only when you set SATA Port1 - Port6 to [AHCI] and allow you to enable or disable the SATA port hot-plug support.

This entry needs to be set to "Enabled" to allow SATA hot-plugging.

Comment: I have no such option in my BIOS. See the edit to my question.

Comment: @AndroidDev Well, I only gave you the information I had from reading the [user manual](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A97/HelpDesk_Manual/) which indeed looks different to your screenshot but I am pretty confident that **SATA ESP** is short for external SATA port. I'd enable this on the port you wish to hot-plug.

Comment: Ah, hold on a sec. You looked up the manual for the M5A97, but I have the M5A97 R2.0. I actually went down to the basement and dug out the paper manual that came with the motherboard, and it makes no mention of SATA hot-plugging. Nevertheless, I will try toggling SATA ESP and I will report the results.

Comment: @AndroidDev: here's your manual: https://www.asus.com/de/Motherboards/M5A97_R20/HelpDesk_Manual/  - It does not explain ESP but what else should it be?

Comment: @AndroiDev SATA ESP is explained [here.](https://superuser.com/questions/1039619/what-does-sata-esp-set-sata-port1-to-external-sata-port-do) :-)

Comment: @ElderGeek - Yeah, funnily enough I stumbled upon that same link. I just can't reboot my system to try it right now because I've got a bunch of things running and and ~30 browser windows open :)